# Choice of basis for Fujikawa method to derive chiral anomaly

Tags: quantum-anomalies

I am studying the Fujikawa method of determining the chiral anomalies in a $U(1)$ theory. As we know the basis vectors selected are the eigenstates of the Dirac operator. One of the reasons given is that the eigenstates diagonalize the action which is needed for determining an exact quantity such as Ward-Takahashi identities. Anyone care to explain? I am referring to  *Path Integrals and Quantum Anomalies* by Kazuo Fujikawa and Hiroshi Suzuki.

Comment: What exactly do you want us to explain? How the Ward-Takahashi identity follows? Why we need eigenstates of the Dirac operator to derive it? Please be more specific (and tell us what part exactly you don't understand).

Comment: yes. Why do we need eigenstates of the dirac operator to derive it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, I will try to answer why we need Dirac eigenstates in this procedure, but I am not sure if it is anything more that the tautology that the Fujikawa method is precisely *defined* by using the Dirac eigenstates.

Let me briefly recap what the idea is: (All of this is for a Euclidean theory.)

We consider the infinitesimal local transformaton

$$\psi(x) \mapsto (1 + \mathrm{i}\alpha(x)\gamma_5)\psi(x) \equiv \psi'(x)$$

which, as it is a gauge transformation, should not change the value of the path integral:

$$ Z = \int \mathcal{D}\psi\mathcal{D}\bar\psi \mathrm{e}^{\int\bar\psi \mathrm{i}\not{D}\psi\mathrm{d}^4x} \overset{!}{=} \int\mathcal{D}\psi'\mathcal{D}\bar\psi'\mathrm{e}^{\int \bar\psi\not{D}\psi\mathrm{d}^4x + \int\alpha\partial_\mu j_5^\mu\mathrm{d}^4x}$$

To derive the anomaly term, we must examine what the change of the measure $\mathcal{D}\psi \mapsto \mathcal{D}\psi'$ is. In general, we can say that it is, by the usual transformation formulae for Grassmannian integrations, $\det(M)^{-1}$ for the operator acting as $\psi' = M\psi$.

Now, we must recall that the functional measure $\mathcal{D}\psi$ is only *defined* in the limit of some (UV) regularized theory, it does not exist on its own.. So to actually calculate the correct $\det(M)$, we must obtain it as the limit $\lim_{\Lambda \rightarrow \infty}\det(M_\Lambda)$ of some $M_\Lambda$ and some UV cutoff scale (not necessarily hard) $\Lambda$. UV regulators suppress high momenta. And what are the eigenstates of the Dirac operator? ... Right, they are the momentum modes! So, the most natural regularisation of our theory is to exponentially suppress states with high Dirac eigenvalues as per

$$ \widetilde{\psi}_n = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\not{D}^2}{2\Lambda}}\psi_n$$

where the $\psi_n$ are the unregularised Dirac eigenstates. And by choosing the regulator that way, the only consistent way to define the measure is to see it as the integral over the coefficients of these modes, i.e.

$$\mathcal{D}\psi = \lim_{\Lambda \rightarrow \infty}\prod_n \mathrm{d}\widetilde{a}_n$$

where $\psi = \sum_n \widetilde{a}_n\widetilde{\psi}_n$. (The sum over the $n$ is actually an integral if we use no IR cutoff, but it doesn't matter here, you could as well use one, but it clutters notation a bit and contributes nothing insightful.)

Now, the rest of the Fujikawa anomaly method follows through as hopefully described in your book. I hope this is at least an approximate answer to your question.

Comment: My question was Why do we need the eigenstates for deriving  the ward takahashi identities ,which usually follows from the path integral derivation without the need for any sort of basis eigenstates. Deriving the WT identities was one of the reasons given in the book for selecting the so called "standard basis" as fujikawa himself terms the basis set in his paper.

Comment: The non-anomalous Ward-Takahashi identities follow without needing the Dirac eigenstates, they simply follow from invariance of the measure and my second equation (if your book says something else, I'm afraid it's probably wrong). Deriving the anomalous Ward-Takahashi identities amounts to determining $\det(M)$, and I think I have made plausible why we should choose Dirac eigenstates to calculate that. One could argue that one always needs to proceed as in the anomalous case to really prove that the measure is invariant, however.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of regulator has nothing to do with the choice of basis. The usual choice of regulator is
$$
f(-\not D^2/\Lambda^2)
$$
which is universal, and makes no reference to any specific basis.

There is a choice of basis that makes the regulator particularly simple to work with, namely a basis of eigenfunctions of $\not D$. In such a basis, the regulator can be expressed as
$$
f(-\lambda^2/\Lambda^2)
$$
with $\lambda$ the eigenvalues of $\not D$. This basis simplifies the evaluation of $f$, but there is nothing that forces you to use this basis. You can choose any basis you want -- that is precisely the point of bases -- but if you do not make a smart choice, you will have to work much harder.

To give a trivial example, the partition function of a QM system is
$$
Z=\text{tr}(\exp(-\beta H))
$$
This can be evaluated in any basis you want, but the energy eigenbasis is particularly convenient
$$
Z=\sum_E e^{-\beta E}
$$
You can also compute $Z$ in a position basis if you want. But the calculation might become more cumbersome than in the energy basis.

---

Another important fact, which is perhaps more tangential to the question but seems important to me, is that you are not really evaluating the anomaly of the axial symmetry. What you are evaluating is the mixed anomaly between the axial symmetry and the gauge group.

As such, what exactly is anomalous is a matter of conventions. A mixed anomaly in $G_1\times G_2$ can be moved around -- there are counterterms that shift the anomaly from being a pure $G_1$ anomaly to a pure $G_2$ anomaly, and anything in between. Of course, in your example $G_2$ is the gauge group, and therefore we are forced to move the anomaly to $G_1$, as a gauge anomaly is forbidden.

This freedom to redefine mixed anomalies is reflected, in this particular case, in the freedom to choose different regulators; some regulators might make the axial symmetry non-anomalous, consistent with the fact that counterterms might make it look like a pure gauge anomaly instead. But this is forbidden: gauge groups shall not be anomalous. If a regulator preserves the axial symmetry but breaks the gauge group instead, that regulator is a bad one, and cannot be used.

Comment: This not does motivate that particular choice of regulator.

Comment: Also, the chiral gauge symmetry is anomalous: https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.85.49

Comment: See section 22.2 of Weinberg's *Quantum Theory of Fields*. 

Quote: *"Note that we do not take the regulator function to be a function of [...] $D^\mu D_\mu$, because we need it to regulate not only the determinant but also the fermion propagator $\not{D}^{\text{-}1}$."*

The question is fundamentally asking why this particular choice of regularisation is chosen, let alone the separate question of why the regulator function is chosen as $f(\hat O/\Lambda^2)$. Given that form of the regulator, why is $\hat O$ chosen as $\not{D}$ or $\not{D}^2$?

Comment: This happens to be the choice which diagonalises the fermion action. It also happens to be gauge covariant. Here's another choice which is gauge covariant: $D_\mu D^\mu$. It is not a sufficient explanation to say that $\not{D}$ is chosen because it makes the regularisation gauge-covariant, because there are other choices that do so. This boils down to the same question: why choose the basis (in this particular regulating procedure which identifies a preferred basis) to be that which diagonalises the action? Weinberg says one factor is that the fermion propagator should also be regularised.

Comment: @Myridium 1) I did not motivate the choice of regulator because the question did not ask about the choice of regulator. It asked about the choice of basis, which is an entirely different question, and I addressed the latter.

Comment: 2) In modern terminology, the chiral anomaly is not an anomaly for the chiral symmetry, but rather a mixed anomaly between the chiral symmetry and the gauge group, see e.g. Tong's lecture notes https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/3anom.pdf, section 3.5.

Comment: 3) As I explained in my answer, there is nothing special about the choice of regulator: you are certainly free to choose other regulators. The different choices correspond to different renormalization schemes. The key point, as I stressed in my answer, is that for mixed flavor-gauge anomalies (of which the chiral anomaly is an example), the gauge part must not be chosen to be anomalous, otherwise the system becomes inconsistent. So you are forced to make the flavor part anomalous, and this breaks the flavor symmetry. The chiral symmetry is not a symmetry of the quantum theory, it is broken.

Comment: 4) For some reason, you keep asking about a choice of basis. I don't know how to make it more clear than this: the choice of basis is an entirely orthogonal question, and, again, entirely irrelevant. You can choose whatever basis you want. If you choose a bad one, the calculation is more complicated but the final result is the same. The relevant question is the choice of *regulator*, not the choice of *basis*. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) And, again, different regulators are fine -- they differ by counterterms. If the anomaly involves a gauge part (and here it does), then the only condition is that the gauge part is non-anomalous. This is achieved by $\not D^2$ but not by $D^2$, hence the former is a good regulator but the latter is not. In this case, the relevant couterterm breaks gauge invariance, i.e., it is not an admissible counterterm.

Comment: Okay, seems like this is something which cannot be answered without delving into renormalisation and counter terms.

Comment: "The only condition is that the gauge part is non-anomalous. This is achieved by $\not D^2$ but not by $D^2$, hence the former is a good regulator but the latter is not." - the gauge part is non-amolous and the chiral part is anomalous. That's not really something that one 'chooses'.... Perhaps you would care to answer the question by addressing exactly how $D^2$ results in an inconsistent quantisation. And in the process, why all choices of regularisation result in either the same anomaly or are inconsistent.