# B and L violation by non-perturbative electroweak effects

Tags: non-perturbative, mssm

I was reading about the definition of R-parity on this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356 (pg. 53 54). The author says that postulating B and L numbers conservation in the MSSM is sub-optimal as

1. In the SM their conservation is not postulated but arises from the absence of any renormalisable term in the Lagrangian associated to their violation
2. B and L violation can occur in small amounts due to the presence of non-perturbative electroweak effects anyway

About reason 2, the author references a paper by t'Hooft which, unfortunately, I cannot download. My question is: what are these non-perturbative effects?

I have seen that there are other questions and answers here related to this topic but I was looking for some less technical, general, or even qualitative
answer.

Thank you!

Comment: 't Hooft's [publication list](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub.html) includes [this link to a paper](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/symm_br_bell_jackiw.pdf) on baryon and lepton number nonconservation in $V-A$ gauge theories with charm; is that the one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baryon non-conservation in the quantum theory is caused by the [chiral anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly), which leads to the baryon current $j_B^\mu = \sum_i \bar q_i \gamma^\mu q_i$ being not conserved as
$$ \partial_\mu j_B^\mu \propto F\wedge F$$
where $F$ is the field strength tensor of the electroweak field. Now, $\int \partial_\mu j_B^\mu \propto \int F\wedge F$ is a topological invariant, associated to the [instanton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instanton) (see also) sector we're in. The instanton is essentially the classical solution - the vacuum - we're basing our quantum field theoretic perturbative expansion around (see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127880/50583) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/224608/50583) post of mine). This means instantons are invisible from the perturbative viewpoint - you have to fix one to do perturbation theory.

Furthermore, if one expands the partition function as a Taylor series around vanishing coupling constant, which essentially defines the perturbative approach, the instanton contributions vanish because they are suppressed with a factor $\mathrm{e}^{-1/g}$ whose Taylor expansion at vanishing coupling is identically zero, and hence doesn't appear in the perturbation series (cf. [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/non-perturbative+effect)).

Graphically, the anomaly and hence the non-conservation is associated to the triangle diagrams
[image]

see [*"Lectures on Anomalies"*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0634) by Bilal.