# How does the instanton break the $U(1)_A$ symmetry in QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, instantons

The $U(1)_A$ symmetry in QCD is anomalous. Its supposed to be broken by the instantons. Can anyone physically describe how does that happen?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150435/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122206/50583